# Regular Expression - Show Date and Time according to UTC in C#

Tags: c#, regex, datetime

My timestamp is like this: 20151020T160000Z

I wrote following logic to get date time from the timestamp:

```
replace(string(20151020T160000Z), '^(19|20\d\d)(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])T(20|21|22|23|[0-1]\d)([0-5]\d)([0-5][0-9])Z', '$3-$2-$1 $4:$5')
```

The output with this code is: 20-10-2015 16:00
but I want output according to UTC+2 i.e: **20-10-2015 18:00**

Comment: Regex isn't a very good choice for doing anything related to arithmetic.  You should capture the timestamp as a date variable first and then increment/offset it.

Comment: The problem here is if I capture timestamp as a date variable it is works fine until and unless timestamp is not null. if timestamp is null showing me the date 01.01.0001 which I do not want to show. thats why I used timestamp as string.

Comment: Sure this is C#?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this is with a combination of `DateTime.ParseExact` and the utilities supplied by`TimeZoneInfo`. Note I do not know what timezone you're using so I used one roughly +2 from UTC.

```
var input = "20151020T160000Z";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
var newDT = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Middle East Standard Time"));
Console.WriteLine(newDT);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/RQGOC94507